# what is the best way to do django relational?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just learn to program Django, and until now when creating models and relation i always write it like this :

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Factory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but now my models seems cant used when im learning to use admin.StackInline to add extra car when i want to add new data for factory in my admin, is there any problem with my code? what is the best practice for relating a models in Django? thanks

Comment: I think you have your relationship backwards.  Are you sure that you want `car = models.ForeignKey(Car..)` in your Factory Model? I would think you would want `factory = models.ForeignKey(Factory...)` in your `Car` model. But I could be wrong.  Is it that, a `Factory` makes one kind of `Car` and a `Car` is made at one of more `Factory`s?  If so your models are correct.

Comment: @RedCricket so its should be foreignkey of factory inside car class? am i doing it all wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure.  If `factory_1` and `factory_2` make `car_a` and `factory_3` makes `car_b`, then your models are correct

Comment: If you are having trouble with Django's admin portal then you should post your admin.py and maybe some screen shots of the admin web page(s).

Comment: @RedCricket if im using your suggestion sir, now i can implement the admin.StackedInline to generate another extra car in factory, but until now all my models beside this factory and car using the backwards style like what im doing before sir, i dont know should i rewrite all my models or let it be ?, because in other model i dont need stackedInline for Django admin

Comment: Let the models be.  What we should look at is your admin.py code. Also if you clarify what the problem is.  Maybe with a screen shot of your admin change model screen of the model you have issue with.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @RedCricket im using Django 2.1 sir 
my admin.py look like this sir and its worked without changing it, i just change my models like what you suggest me.

`
class CarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Car
    extra = 5
    
class FactoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .....
    inlines = [CarInline]

admin.site.register(Factory, FactoryAdmin)
` 
now it give me 5 input of car every time i want to add a factory sir, so from your statement i dont need to change the rest of model i have create sir? thanks for your respond sir